# Spring boot admin listing kubernetes internal urls. Not able to navigate to the application page

Tags: spring-boot, kubernetes, microservices, spring-cloud, spring-boot-admin

**Problem**

- Trying to use Spring boot admin to do a deep monitoring of spring boot micro services running in Kubernetes.
- Spring boot admin listing the micro services but pointing to the internal IPs.

> Spring boot admin application listing page showing the internal IP

[image: Spring boot admin application listing page showing the internal IP]

> The application details page has almost zero info

[image: The application details page almost zero info]

**Details**

- Kubernetes 1.15
- Spring boot applications are getting discovered by Spring boot admin using Spring cloud discovery
- spring-cloud-kubernetes version 1.1.0.RELEASE
- The problem is that the IPs are of internal pod network and would not be accessible to the users in any real world scenario.

> Any hints on how to approach this scenario ? Any alternatives ?

Also I was wondering how spring boot admin would behave in case of pods with more than one replica. I think it is close to impossible to point to a unique pod replica through ingress or node port.

> Hack I am working on

If I can start another pod which exposes the Linux desktop to the end user. From a browser of this desktop, user may be able to access the pod network ips. It is just a wild thought as a hack.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Spring Boot Admin register each application/client based on its name by below property.

```
spring.boot.admin.client.instance.name=${spring.application.name}
```

If all your pods have same name it can register based on individual ips by enabling *perfer-ip* property (which is false by default):

```
spring.boot.admin.client.instance.prefer-ip=true
```

**In your case**, you want to SBA to register based on the Kubernetes load balanced url, then *service-base-url* property should be set the corresponding application's url.

```
spring.boot.admin.client.instance.service-base-url=http://myapp.com
```

Comment: If I have two instances of the client ( my application) created using the replica feature of the pod. In this scenario I have only one url pointing to the Two clients. So I assume this may not work in a real scenario.

Comment: But certainly, thank you for the input, looks like this could solve my problem in a single client scenario.

Comment: Hi Arunvg, our application also have multiple replicas. This works fine for us. SBA doesn't know about the individual pods instead it registers the load-balanced url. Just, you should not enable the prefer-ip property. You could give it a try :)

Comment: Sure Let me try that out. Your confidence is giving me hope :)

Comment: Yup it worked. I was looking to a totally different direction

Comment: great, enjoy.. :)

Comment: Did this solution with service-base-url show two instances if it was still resolving without the ip? Or just once instance rebalanced?